# AWS Cognito API `AWSMobileClient.default().addUserStateListener` only fires when user authentication state changes

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using xcode 11 with swift 4. I am following the docs for aws cognito here https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication and in `AppDelegate.swift`, I have:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // initialize AWS amplify
    let apiPlugin = AWSAPIPlugin(modelRegistration: AmplifyModels())

    do {
        try Amplify.add(plugin: apiPlugin)
        try Amplify.configure()
    } catch {
        // Navigate to page showing bad network connection
        print("Failed to configure Amplify \(error)")
    }

    AWSMobileClient.default().addUserStateListener(self) { (userState, info) in
        switch (userState) {
            case .signedOut:
                // user clicked signout button and signedout
                print("AppDelegate.application state: user signed out")
            case .signedIn:
                print("AppDelegate.application state: user signed in: \(userState)")
            case .signedOutUserPoolsTokenInvalid:
                print("need to login again.")
            default:
                print("unsupported")
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

The `AWSMobileClient.default().addUserStateListener` only fires when the user is logging in or signing up for the first time. if the user is already authenticated. then `addUserStateListener` does not fire. This is an issue because I need to get the user's account token to access his/her information. Am I using the wrong Cognito API? Or is `addUserStateListener` used in the wrong function.

If I use the other Cognito API

```
AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState, error) ... }
```

It fires each time, but I cannot access the user token from this api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the user token by using the AWSAppSync api and this method in you app delegate either by extending appDelegate or using your own custom class as I did.

```
class CognitoPoolProvider : AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProviderAsync {


    func getLatestAuthToken(_ callback: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {

        AWSMobileClient.default().getTokens { (token, error) in

            if let error = error {
                callback(nil,error)
            }
            callback(token?.accessToken?.tokenString, error)
        }
    }
}
```

So, in my appDelegate I did something like this

```
var appSyncClientBridge : AWSAppSyncClient?

    /// Sets the configuration settings for application's AWSAppSync Client.
    func appSyncSetup()throws -> AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration{

        let cache = try AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration()
        let serviceConfig = try AWSAppSyncServiceConfig()

        let appSyncConfiguration = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(appSyncServiceConfig: serviceConfig,
                                                                     userPoolsAuthProvider: CognitoPoolProvider(),
                                                                     cacheConfiguration: cache)


        return appSyncConfiguration
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        do {
            let configFile = try appSyncSetup()
            appSyncClientBridge = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: configFile)
        }
        catch(let error){
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return true
    }
```

UPDATE:

If the user is already logged in. You can create a method like this one.

```
func getTokens(){
        let getPool = CognitoPoolProvider()

        func getToken(completion: @escaping (Result<String,Error>)->Void){
            getPool.getLatestAuthToken { (token, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                if let token = token {
                    completion(.success(token))
                }
            }
        }

        getToken { (result) in
            print(("This is the token — \(String(describing: try? result.get() as String))"))
        }
    }
```

If you place this in your viewDidLoad you'll be able to access the user token. In this example it's just printed out, but I think from here you'll be able to use it for what you need.

Comment: does your AppDelegate extend `AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProviderAsync`?

Comment: No, that's what the CognitoPoolProvider does. You can do it either way. I was just tying to keep separation of concerns so I broke it in two. You can extend AppDelegate and add that method I used in CognitoPoolProvider and it should have the same result for you.

Comment: hm ok. and where does `AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration` load from? I try installing it as a Pod but there is no such thing. It doestn load from AmplifyPlugins, AWSMobileClient, or AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

Comment: pod 'AWSUserPoolsSignIn', '~> 2.13.0'

Comment: hm ok I did that and `import AWSUserPoolsSignIn` in `AppDelegate`, but I'm still seeing the error message: "use of unresolved identifier 'AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration'. And this is  after cleaning the build folder, restarting xcode. etc. To be clear, I really just need to load the user's account information, such as user' email from Cognito. Getting the user's token is not strictly necessary since I can also look up info via email.

Comment: import AWSAppSync
import AWSMobileClient

This is my pod file ->  
  pod 'AWSAppSync', '~> 3.1.0'
  pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.13.0'      
  pod 'AWSAuthUI', '~> 2.13.0'          
  pod 'AWSUserPoolsSignIn', '~> 2.13.0'

Comment: ok almost there! How is `getLatestAuthToken` used? In the cod above, it never excplicity call `CognitoPoolProvider().getLatestAuthToken`

Comment: From what I can remember, it will only call it when the database is actually needs to like when writing to a database. I haven't used this in a bit but let me do some research.

Comment: Yup, so my use case is to load the user's data token or email for Cognito, and use that to find the rest of the user's data in Amplify GraphQL

Comment: Hey I am going to update my response. I found a solution I think...